# How to get volume up button action for taking pick from camera in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera

I got the action of volume up action but after appearing camera volume up button not working again.if i dismiss camera then it is working.
Please help me.
i'm using volume up button action code like this:

```
self.volumeButtonHandler = [JPSVolumeButtonHandler volumeButtonHandlerWithUpBlock:^{
        [self click_Volume];
    } downBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Down");
    }];
```

I'm using  below code for taking picture.

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls=YES;
    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        collView_Product = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.overlayView.frame.size.height-200,self.view.frame.size.width,100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
        [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [collView_Product setDataSource:self];
        [collView_Product setDelegate:self];
        collView_Product.scrollEnabled = YES;
        collView_Product.pagingEnabled = NO;
        [collView_Product registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
        [collView_Product setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.0/255.0 green:53.0/255.0 blue:60.0/255.0 alpha:0.8]];
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing =-2;
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = -1;
        [collView_Product setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [self.overlayView addSubview:collView_Product];
      self.overlayView = nil;
    }
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```